# About dbfilter not catching the correct database on Odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have `example.com` site that is now `subdomain.example.com` (had been renamed to that subdomain)

On my odoo config file I have:

```
dbfilter = ^%d$
```

The database name is `example`. As far as I know, that should still catch the database but seems that I can't access the site. Not sure if it's an odoo issue or if I'm missing something on my nginx configuration which is this: https://pastebin.com/KJxbJPKz (this used to work when the site was named example.com, I made the corresponding changes)

I'm mentioning nginx because I'm getting the 404 error specified when accessing port 80 and not port 443 which is weird since I'm accessing the site using https

I must clarify that the corresponding upstreams are defined and working (I have other sites working on that server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a misunderstanding, I thought that setting `dbfilter = ^%d$` will catch the database called example regarding of the subdomain name.

So I thought and saw some forum answers pointing that sub.example.com, as well as othersub.example.com, will select *example* as the database as it was the domain. But it works the other way. I mean **Working** in this way, **if subdomain.example.com is your site, and dbfilter is set as before, the database name should be *subdomain* and not *example***.

My solution was to rename the database to *subdomain* and after that regenerate the web assets so it works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering Database names equal to a subdomain,
So you need to manually enter every subdomain in **/etc/hosts**, only then it starts working.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please note that odoo is not correctly filtering the database name in this case. I don't think is something related to DNS or resolving issues. Anyway I've added `127.0.0.1    subdomain.example.com` to my /etc/hosts file and still nothing. I've restarted the corresponding services of course.

Comment: This is simply not true. You don't need any entries in /etc/hosts when set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the string of the database name in the dbfilter key in the `odoo.conf` file

For example: if the database's name is `test` then `dbfilter = ^test$` or `^tes$`

Answer (score 0):

dbfilter = ^%d$

does catch the domain only, when www is the subdomain. If you want to catch the domain name in a constellation like subdomain.domain.com, then you have to set the host parameter %h.