# Can not edit any webpage on odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

using Odoo 13. I can't edit any page on the website (or the menu). I can see that this files are getting a 404 error (not loading) and they for sure are the problem here:

```
/web/content/261-c2af7d4/web_editor.summernote.css
/web/content/262-c2af7d4/web_editor.summernote.js
```

I've tried regenerating the assets but still getting that. Any hint what to check for then?

PS: Not sure if related, that site domain was changed and its database renamed in order to allow dbfilter to catch it. Look this solved post: [About dbfilter not catching the correct database on Odoo 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035343/about-dbfilter-not-catching-the-correct-database-on-odoo-13)

Comment: If you change the database name, you should also rename the filestore directory, because it is using the database name.

Comment: @CZoellner can you ellaborate more please? Do you mean to set or change the data_dir in the odoo config file or some system parameter under the technical menu? what if I have many databases? Thanks.

Comment: @CZoellner seems that attachments are stored on the db and not on filestore. data_dir is not set on the config file. I can see attachments at "Settings->Technical->Database structure->Attachments"

Comment: No, they aren't stored in db per default, but in the default folder. Where this is depends on your odoo setup (how was it installed, etc.). And at the end there is one folder for each db, named by the db name. So if you change the db name, but not the folders name, Odoo shouldn't find any data for its attachments. The attachments in Odoo or in database table `ir_attachment` just have paths to the real data on your machine.

Comment: @CZoellner thanks for your comments. On the db I can see in the url column something like  `/web/content/616-5877ccf/filename`  where 616-5877ccf is actually random and different for every file (seems no db name associated). As I said `data_dir` is not set on the config file since the beggining. I've posted an answer before seeing your last comment. Please feel free to ellaborate more as an answer so I can pick it. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you don't have the data_dir in config, Odoo will store them on your machine. IIRC it is somewhere in the user's home directory, possibly hidden. With user i mean the os' user Odoo is started with.

Comment: @CZoellner got it. I found the folder `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore`. Do you suggest to transfer the contents of the old database dir to the new database dir?

Comment: I would just stop Odoo, rename the old folder and start Odoo. But keep some simple advice in mind: make backups ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner thanks again! Well, renamed the folder, restarted odoo, site goes pretty wrong, so revert it :) I guess maybe recreating the assets, etc. But as it's a pretty new/clean site I'll just leave it as it's working and can't see any more erros on console. Fortunatelly those two files where just the problem (hope so).

Answer (score 0):

This was effectively due a database name change.

Checking at *Settings -> Technical -> Database structure -> Attachments* I was able to confirm that there where no files associated with `web_editor.summernote.css` and `web_editor.summernote.js`, as a quick fix I've borrowed those files from another site and uploaded them.

So @CZoellner gives me another hint that could be a better solution if you already have a website with a lot of attachments, and is to rename the filestore directory from your old database name to the new database name.

If you didn't set `data_dir` on your odoo config file, it's likely possible that the folder is located at `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore` of the user that runs odoo. There you will find folders with the corresponding database name, just rename and restart odoo so you're files will be present again.

PS: Always do backups.